# How to copy an image using a URL and paste into Excel (through xlwings) without first downloading the image?

Tags: python, image, xlwings

Apologies if this has been asked somewhere before, but I couldn't find a good answer.  I'm trying to take an image URL obtained from scraping a website and use it to paste the image into an Excel worksheet without saving the image somewhere first.  I guess this would be equivalent to right-clicking the image, copying, then pasting into Excel if someone were to try this manually.

Right now, I'm using skimage to get the image to pop up:

```
from skimage import io
io.imshow(io.imread('urlhere.com'))
io.show()
```

However, I don't think there is a way to work with the image like this and paste it into Excel using xlwings.  I've seen people mention things like `urllib.request.urlretrieve` and `PIL` but these only seem to work if I want to save the image somewhere first and then bring it into Excel.

I feel like I'm missing some kind of obvious answer, but is there a way to skip the saving part and just copy the image from its URL to put it somewhere else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, I was able to figure this out so I thought I'd post the answer:

xlwings only allows for pictures from a filepath or matplotlib figures to be added to Excel files.  Therefore, I had to create a matplotlib figure of the image, turn its axes off, and insert it into the Excel file.  There may be a better way to do it, but this is what worked for me:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
import xlwings as xw

image_url = 'urlname.com'

fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(io.imread(image_url))

wb = xw.Book(r'file\path\document.xlsm')
dashboard = wb.sheets['sheet1']
dashboard.pictures.add(fig)
```